# Finding the minimum number of required deletions to have a non-repeating string

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, python-3.x, edit-distance

I wrote code for the following problem:

> Given a string, print out the number of deletions required so that the adjacent alphabets are distinct.

Please suggest different methods by which I can increase the speed of execution.

```
tst = int(input())
for i in range(0,tst):
    str = input()
    length = len(str)
    str = list(str)
    j=0;
    count = 0
    while(j<length):
       if(j+1<length):
            if((str[j] == str[j+1])):
                del str[j+1]
                count+=1
                length-=1
            else:
                j+=1
       else:
            j+=1
    print(count)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's your culprit:

> ```
> del str[j+1]
> ```

When you remove one character from a string, all subsequent characters need to be shifted into the hole that you create.  That changes your algorithm from O(*Length*) to a worst-case scenario of O(*Length*<sup>2</sup>), if every character is the same.

Additionally, your inner loop looks a lot like C code.  Here is one way to reformulate it.

```
def count_consecutive_deletions(s):
    deletions = 0
    for i in range(1, len(s)):
        if s[i] == s[i - 1]:
            deletions += 1
    return deletions

def testcases():
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        yield input()

for case in testcases():
    print(count_consecutive_deletions(case))
```